# Discord Bot Dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Hi I am trying to get this discord bot dashboard up and running but am not too sure on how to do that. To run it I need to do node dashboard server.js? I mean when I do that it shows shows no module with that directory. I am not sure on what I am suppose to do here.

Here is my code in the link
https://sourceb.in/1xryoN6146

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do `node (filename)` to run the file. Make sure that your terminal is in the same directory as your file that you want to run and it should work.